# VBA Internet Explorer Big Trouble with dynamic dropdown list

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm new on the website so here is my first post!

I must check many applications of cars with the website: 
http://www.monroe.com/en-US/. My applications are all in my Excel file. On the website we have 3 dropdown lists (the year, make and model). I have 2 problems in the interaction Vba-Internet.

Let's say a research for a 2010 Chevrolet Aveo5

My first problem is that when I select the first dropdown (year), the second one is not working. It's like that the second dropdrown is frozen. I noticed  in the HTML code that when I was selected my first dropdown during my macro the second one was staying at disabled = "disabled". So I tried in my code to change the property disabled=false or disabled="" but it failed also.

My second problem is the value in the HTML code. Instead of having the year(eg:2010) this is a code like this (value "42621"). So I cannot use my year stocked in my excel file as a value. The year in the HTML code in only find as a innerhtml, innertext, outertext, textcontent.... in my vba code.

1. Is there a way to use appropriately the drowdown list?
2. Can I use the years in my excel file over the value writen in the HTML code?

Here is my Code:

```
Sub Research()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim IEDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim Year As HTMLSelectElement
Dim Make As HTMLSelectElement
Dim Model As HTMLSelectElement
Dim Button As HTMLFormElement

IE.navigate "http://www.monroe.com/en-US/"
IE.Visible = True
While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

Set IEDoc = IE.document

Set Make = IEDoc.all("widget-ymm-make-desktop")
Make.disabled = False

Set Year = IEDoc.all("widget-ymm-year-desktop")
Year.Value = "42621"  'I would like to put the year 2010 from my excel instead

'Once the year is selected the dropdown make is not working or is frozen
Make.textContent = "Chevrolet"

Set Model = IEDoc.all("widget-ymm-model-desktop")
Model.textContent = IEDoc.all("Aveo5")

Set Button = IEDoc.all("lookup-form-desktop")
Button.submit
While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

Set IE = Nothing
Set IEDoc = Nothing
IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Here is a part of the HTML Code:

```
    <select name="widget-ymm-year-desktop" class="widget-ymm-year widget-ymm-year-desktop form-control" id="widget-ymm-year-desktop" aria-required="true" required="">
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Though the web page doesn't load for me maybe it doesn't work in my region, as far as I know these would be the dependent drop downs on the web page i.e. the second will only be activated or accept a value once the first drop down accepts the value and the second drop down gets internally loaded with possible items as per the selection in the first drop down and this would be the same for the third drop down. So after changing the value of the first drop down, use application.wait to give it some time to load the second drop down items internally........

Comment: ...... and then get the ie.document again so that you have the latest html document. So use Set IEDoc = IE.document again to get it and set the value for the second drop down and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work even if I let time the web site to load. I tried with a readystate=complete + an application.wait with 4 seconds and my second dropdown list is still at the mode disabled. In the HTML code we can cleary see disabled="disabled" and as soon as I decide to do it manually with my keyboard the mode disabled change for disabled= "".

Comment: Well since I am not able to view the web page, I cannot assist you any more with this. My apologies.

Comment: I forgot to tell that I also tried to Set IEDoc = IE.document but my second dropdown list is always frozen. I think that the point is to find a way to manage the HTML once the first dropdown is set. The dropdown lists are dynamic and depend on each other.